# I'm not able to access another activity from one activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent

Why my intent not working,  i can't use my second activity from my main activity why?

```
`java.lang.RuntimeException:
Unable to instantiate activity
Componentinfo{com.softltd.application/
com.softltd.application.Second):
java.lang.lllegalAccessException: java.lang.Cl
ass is not
accessible from java.lang.Class
pComponentFactory>
at`
```

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You'll need to edit your question and put [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question.

Comment: Please edit the quesiton and include the complete stack trace and the relevant parts of your manifest.